# Sonarqube plugin to execute PL/SQL test procedures

Tags: sql, plsql, sonarqube

I'm working with `Sonarqube` recently & we had a requirement to scan `PL/SQL` projects, which we are able to do using [SonarPLSQL plugin](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarplsql.html).

But there are some test cases written in `Procedures` (inside a PL/SQL package), which perform testing over the the source code (present in a different Pl/SQL package).

I've a requirment in which I want sonar to perform code-coverage anaylsis.

Is there any sonar plugin avaliable that can execute these test cases and provide me the code-coverage metrics?

Also, if there is an alternate approach for my problem, please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Analysis will not *execute* your tests. It will only read *some* reports of your test execution. You must execute your tests independently and then convert the results into the [Generic Test Data format](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) for inclusion in your analysis.

Comment: @reiley if this answered your question, you should consider accepting it.